# Assigned value to a member of nested structure arrays and now it won't print

Tags: arrays, c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Servidor
{
    int codigo_servidor[256];
    char nome_servidor[256];
    char siape_servidor[256];
    char cpf_servidor[256];
    char nascimento_servidor[256];
    char endereco_servidor[256];
    char rg_servidor[256];
    char salario_servidor[256];
    char tipo_servidor[256];

    struct Veiculo
    {
        int codigo_veiculo;
        char modelo_veiculo[256];
        char descricao_veiculo[256];
        char marca_veiculo[256];
    } veiculo[100];

} servidor;

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!");

    servidor servidor[100];

    servidor[0].veiculo[0].codigo_veiculo = 100;
    printf("%d", servidor[0].veiculo[0].codigo_veiculo);

    return 0;
}
```

This was working a moment ago, now I compiled and it won't print. Hello World does print, though, so it's most likely related to the structures.

Comment: `servidor servidor[100];` is about 8MB in size. Almost certainly too big for a local/stack variable. Use a smaller array or dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: I ran it with `gcc (Raspbian 10.2.1-6+rpi1) 10.2.1 20210110` and it outputted(?) `Hello World!100`. Seems to be okay. Probably you have a small stack.

Comment: _Side note:_ In this instance, because you do `veiculo[100];` (i.e. it's _not_ anonymous) there's no particular advantage to nesting the `Veiculo` struct definition. This is, perhaps, more flexible: `struct Veiculo { ... }; typedef struct Servidor { ... struct Veiculo veiculo[100]; } servidor;`. Now, you can do: `struct Veiculo *vptr = &servidor[3].veiculo[7]; printf("%d\n",vptr->codigo_veiculo);`

Answer (score 0):

You try to print to stdout which is buffered, so your text is buffered until you call:

1. exit()
2. fflush(stdout)
3. or just print a new line, printf("\n")

you can print to stderr which is not buffered, without typing the new line

1. fprintf(stderr, "my text");